# Installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 - But no boot menu, only booting Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

Windows 7 is installed on my first SSD. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is installed on my second SSD. But when I start my PC it only boots Ubuntu and no boot menu appears. I can not get into Windows 7 anymore.
In the BIOS, boot option priorities, I can only choose between my CD/DVD drive and the SSD, where Windows (edit: sorry, I said Ubuntu, but it's the SSD, where Windows is installed) is installed. That's weird. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

For more details, refer this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Please make sure that both Windows and Ubuntu are installed in EFI mode.
Also disable secure boot in BIOS.

Comment: I have got this error: "GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again."

Comment: Some more details - screen shot and error message

Comment: Now, I got a different error.
[here](http://i.imgur.com/EJ40nIV.png)

Comment: Maybe I should install Ubuntu again. It's done quickly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all : You have to install Ubuntu in the same mode as Windows is installed.

When you have installed Windows in EFI mode, then do this with Ubuntu as well.

Second : When there is no boot menu to be seen, disable GRUB hidden timeout.

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu  

gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Place a `#` in front of `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` - so that it reads now : `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

Save the changed file and execute:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now you should see the boot loader on start, there should be a Windows entry in the boot menu.